# How to drag text from input tag, is it possible to drag from it?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement like search box with autocomolete, after selection I want to drag that into another text box.

Thanks, 
Raghu

Comment: What do you mean by "drag"? how about adding an onChange to your search box, and in the function copy the value to the target text box?

Comment: Show Your efforts, we are not here to do your projects.

Comment: I am able to drag a list from div and drop in text box and I need to drag from textbox to another div

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks for giving replay on that

Comment: Nikhil just  I am asking Idea how  we are able to do or  not

Comment: I have a auto complete search box I am able to select value from that and I need to drag same value from that input box@vincent